# HTTPS security is compromised by http: *.abc.com

Tags: apache, http, https

I have problem while redirecting the http:// url from https:// pages.
http pages are the url formed internally in java code. when redirection happens from https to formed http url pages are not loading properly and showing loading symbols.
 In  browser console error showing as "HTTPS security is compromised by http:www.aabc.com"

when i forcibly try to replace http to https redirection says target page uses older tls version

Comment: "when i forcibly try to replace http to https redirection says target page uses older tls version" .. so, update the server's TLS version to something recent (TLS 1.1 is the *minimum* that should be served these days, hopefully also TLS 1.2/1.3 for more modern clients as well). And keep in mind that even older SSL (and TLS 1.0) offers at least "some, possibly 'broken', encryption" while HTTP offers none.

Comment: Have you try to add reverse proxy which will offload the SSL/TLS?

Comment: @romeo ninov : could u plz help me  to do this?